# How can I fight a boss without summoning using an item?

Tags: terraria

It's always puzzled me how to fight a boss in Terraria without going to an items server and grabbing the boss spawner items.

Can someone tell me how to get to them?

Comment: What boss are you trying to spawn? There is quite a few of them; Each with a question already asked on here. You say "without items", but your not using the legitimate items; Do you also include summoning through harvesting the items the proper way? The items are effectivley a requirement if your wanting to farm the boss, as its quicker and more reliable

Comment: @Timelord64 I am trying to legitimately get to and fight any of the bosses, such as Skeletron. Also, I didn't know specific items were actually required. Soooo thanks

Comment: There are also bosses that spawn as a random event. Examples include Eye of Cthulu, Destroyer, Twins, Skeletron Prime, etc. SKELETRON is summoned by talking to the old man in the dungeon at night

Comment: @JohnSmith oh, okay! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the bosses have a small chance to spawn each night. You will know that one is about to spawn if you receive an ominous message in purple text in the chat.

However relying on this method to spawn a particular boss will take you forever.

If there is a particular boss you wish to fight there is a summoning item that when used will spawn the boss. The ingredients for each item differs.

The best way to work out how to do this for each boss is to go to the wiki page for the boss in question. Say you want to spawn the *Eater of Worlds*: simply type in "Terraria Eater of Worlds" into Google and click the "Terraria.gamepedia.com" link. Doing so will take you to [this page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds). From here just read from the top until you get to the part that says how to summon it. This information is generally in the first few paragraphs. In this case the relevant sentence is: *It is summoned using the Worm Food from within The Corruption, or by destroying 3 Shadow Orbs.* So you now know that the item you are looking to make is called *Worm Food* you can click the link to see how to make it.

Also notice that in the example I used there was an alternate method of spawning the boss, by destroying 3 Shadow Orbs. Several bosses have a similar method of being spawned without items. Such as Skeletron, where you only need to talk to the Old Man at night.

Each boss has different methods and conditions for spawning, you will need to check the wiki for each boss to see how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was really helpful. Well, now I will go on and spam some noobish questions.. jk

Comment: @Beminfire glad to be of help, this more generic question is more useful than asking individually "how to summon the eater" "how to summon x". Teaching to fish as opposed to giving a fish ;)

Comment: It won't take forever if you've never fought the boss before. The chances of them spawning in that case is much higher - Eye of Cthulhu has a 1/3 chance of spawning if you meet its conditions, for example

Comment: If this question isnt closed, it might be useful to link to the respective questions for each boss. I believe they are all covered, but in a lot more detail, as they are more specific questions.

Comment: @Timelord64 why should it be closed? and why would I link to those? I've explained how to summon every boss as well as any boss that will be added in the future.

Comment: @Aequitas how to summon all bosses, by my definition, is too broad. It appears others agree, as this question is already on hold.

Comment: @Timelord64 how is it too broad? I can answer it in 5 words: "you can craft those items" OP isn't asking how to summon each and every boss, they're asking how they can legitimetly summon a boss. they didn't know that they can make those items. My full answer isn't exactly too long and it is far more useful than asking for a single boss as it explains how to summon every boss that currently exists or will be added in patches later and even bosses that were removed if they were curious about that.

Comment: The problem is, the answer itself is pretty vague. Which items do you collect? How, exactly, do you spawn the bosses at night? (It might be a small chance **after** the first encounter, but there are still certain requirements) Who is the old man, and where do you find him? You link to the gamopedia for further reading, but we don't accept links as an answer.

Comment: Again, the point you seem to have ignored entirely, and the point I was initially putting forward, it might be useful to include the specific questions for each boss here on the arqade.